# How does one turn off all writing to attached disks in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, write-protect

I would like to turn off writing to all non-system disks in Windows 7, including indexing, I would like for the functionality to be equivalent to mount -o loop,ro in Linux if possible.  Is there a way to force Windows 7 not to write anything to a disk?